# Why does MyDefrag take so long to Fast Optimize?

Tags: speed, defragment, mydefrag

From recommendations in other questions about defragmenters, I decided to try out MyDefrag. However I'm finding that the Fast Optimize script is running very slowly, specifically it seems to take a very long time over "Reclaiming the NTFS reserved areas" - and the interface implies that this is related to one of my Virtual PC vhd files.

By a long time I mean it's got to 0.0659% after about 5 hours of running. Is this normal, or is there something I can do to improve this.

EDIT: I tried a number of the suggestions posted by Ivo to no avail. I then moved the VHD file that it was stuck on off the disk and it's now running through much quicker. To compare it ran through phase 1 in about 10 minutes, compared to taking 5 hours to get to less than 0.1% of phase 1

Which still makes me wonder why a VHD file was in an "NTFS reserved area", as reserved implies to me that user files shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did appear to be the vhd file that was causing the issue, having moved it off, performed a defrag and then returned it, all subsequent defrags have had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try the older version [JKDefrag](http://www.kessels.com/Jkdefrag/) and see how that one does?

Or else, is there some application running that might interfere with defragmentation?

Not a real solution, but my suggestion would be to just let it run overnight or as a screensaver. Give it time and it will fix (what it can) eventually.

From the MYDefrag FAQ:

> The FastOptimize and FastUpdate scripts will try to perfectly fill gaps with files from above the gap, but if MyDefrag cannot find a perfect fitting combination of files then a (smaller) gap will be left unfilled. The SlowOptimize script will produce cleaner results, but will take more time to finish.
>
> There are many files that cannot be moved while Windows is running, because they are in use by an application, or by a service, or by Windows itself. See the "c:\Program Files\MyDefrag v4.1\MyDefrag.log" file for a list of files that could not be moved. The unmovables can be anywhere on disk and are usually fragmented into microscopically small segments. In other words, the harddisk is not a big block of space where files can be moved at will, but thousands of little blocks bounded by unmovable data.
> Tip: Certain unmovable Windows files cannot be defragmented, but there are things you can do. For more information see the  FAQ Special files
>
> [Defragmentation and optimization](http://www.mydefrag.com/FAQUsing-MyDefragIsVerySlowWhatSpeedCanIExpect.html)
> can take a long time, you will have to
> be patient. In the top of the window
> you will see the current MyDefrag
> activity and normally the program will
> be moving files at a furious rate,
> dozens of small files per second. The
> display is only refreshed once per
> second though, and big files will take
> more time, obviously.
>
> - If your computer becomes unresponsive while running MyDefrag
>   (especially the MyDefrag display) then
>   try the  Slowdown setting to make
>   MyDefrag use less resources. Note: It
>   is normal for your computer to be
>   unresponsive while the $MFT is being
>   moved. This is caused by something
>   inside Windows itself, not MyDefrag.
> - Try turning off your virusscanner. Some virusscanners get exited and scan
>   all the files that MyDefrag is moving,
>   even though MyDefrag does not execute
>   or change the files.
> - Try a reboot. Sometimes the Microsoft defragmentation API can
>   become mysteriously slow and take a
>   minute to move even a small file. I
>   don't know why, but usually a reboot
>   helps.
> - Cleanup old stuff from your harddisk. MyDefrag can move files more
>   efficiently if there is plenty of free
>   space available.
>
> It is impossible to predict how much
> running time a script will take. It
> depends on things such as the
> optimization you have selected, the
> speed of your harddisk, how big the
> files are, how much data is on the
> disk, how the files are currently
> placed, and more. Assuming a harddisk
> speed of 40 megabytes per second, then
> reading 100 gigabytes of data will
> take 100000 / 40 = 2500 seconds (42
> minutes). But MyDefrag has to do a lot
> more than just read the data, it also
> has to write the data, and update the
> MFT/FAT. And it may have to move data
> out of the way before it can place an
> item were it want's it to be. MyDefrag
> will do things as efficiently as
> possible, with as little data movement
> as possible, but it will take a long
> time nonetheless. If you are concerned
> about speed then use the "Fast
> Optimize" script. It will produce very
> good results in a minimum amount of
> time, especially if you use it every
> day.
>
> Tip: For more information about what
> the program is doing run it with the
> "-d 4" commandline parameter, or add a
> line with "Debug(175)" to your
> "C:\Program Files\MyDefrag
> v4.1\Scripts\Settings.MyD" script, and
> while the program is running look at
> your "C:\Program Files\MyDefrag
> v4.1\MyDefrag.debuglog" file.

Comment: I'll second JkDefrag any day. Yet to check 4.0

Comment: So in other words, that means there's a lot of files that needs defragging :)

Comment: MyDefrag is nice, but there's really little reason to move from JKDefrag.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend disabling optimization for virtual disks. It's simple to edit the MyDefrag scripts not to optimize specified directories, for example, where your virtual disk is.

I use [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and found problems getting it to recognize virtual disks after they'd been optimized by the host OS using MyDefrag. I also read elsewhere, sorry I don't have the reference, that virtual disk optimization in the host OS is not a good idea. The recommended approach was to optimize the Virtual Disk within the guest OS.